# Accessing term's tid

Tags: 8, entities

I am trying to loop through a taxonomy term's tid, but somehow all the array elements are protected. It was very easy peasy in Drupal 7 with:

```
 $term_id_1 = $node->field_term['und'][0]['tid'];
```

I am not sure how I could access tid(here is the kint() screenshot):

[image]

and here I how I get this and my broken foreach():

```
public function setCollection($collection) {
$collection_array = [];
$collection_ids =  \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($collection);
kint($collection_ids);
foreach ($collection_ids as $collection_id) {
  $keys = $collection_id->values;
  foreach ($keys as $key){
    $collection_array[] = $key->tid;
  }
}

$this->collection = $collection_array;
```

}

Question 1-> Is taxonomy terms are node?

Question 2-> Is this line correct to get the fields?

```
  $collection_ids =  \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($collection);
```

Question 3-> Can anyone lead me to get access 'tid' from this protected 'values' array?

Warm regards.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do `$term->id()` which should return the term id if `$term` is a [Term](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!taxonomy!src!Entity!Term.php/class/Term/8.2.x) object. See [id()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3Aid/8.2.x).

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1 - Taxonomy Terms are an Entity in Drupal 8 (`Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term`), not a node.

Answer 2 - Is your parameter `$collection` a single ID or an array ID's? If it's a single ID, then yes. If it's an array of ID's then you should be using `Term::loadMultiple()`.

Answer 3 - You can call `Term::id()` on the object, so in your case it would be `$collecion_id->id()`.